# Checkbutton checked delete and unchecked remain in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a Tkinter Grocery App where the combo box adds the grocery item, while the shopper could check the checkbox to remove the grocery item.

```py
check_box_list = []

def add_list():
    global my_checkbutton, var, my_combo
    var = IntVar()
    my_checkbutton = tb.Checkbutton(grocery_list, text=my_combo.get(), 
                                    variable=var, bootstyle="danger")
    my_checkbutton.pack(pady=10)
    
    check_box_list.append(my_checkbutton)

def remove_list(): 
    for i in check_box_list: 
        if var.get() == 1:
            i.destroy()  
        else:
            i.pack()
```

I want to delete the checked item and leave the unchecked item on the grocery list. However, when I clicked on the selected items to check, it appeared that all items had been deleted. Why? and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you use same *global variable* `var` for all the checkbuttons, so `var` will always be associated to the last checkbutton created.  If the last checkbutton is checked to be deleted, all the checkbuttons will be deleted.

Use an attribute of the checkbutton to store the reference of the tkinter variable instead:

```py
def add_list():
    # not necessary to use global variable
    var = tk.IntVar()
    my_checkbutton = tb.Checkbutton(grocery_list, text=my_combo.get(),
                                    variable=var, bootstyle="danger")
    my_checkbutton.pack(pady=10)
    my_checkbutton.var = var   # save the reference to var

    check_box_list.append(my_checkbutton)

def remove_list():
    for w in check_box_list:
        if w.var.get() == 1:
            w.destroy()
```

Comment: How could I get the checkbox's value?  I need to remove the items from the check_box_list. as It's var is  an int not a string!